# Azure IoT remote monitoring issue

Tags: azure, monitoring, iot, azure-logic-apps

I am following the document "IoT remote monitoring and notifications with Azure Logic Apps connecting your IoT hub and mailbox".

In the section "Add a service bus queue" I am stuck at the step number 3:

```
 "Open the service bus queue, and then click Shared access policies > + Add."
```

When I create a new Access Policy, after a while the following error occurs.

```
SubCode=40000. Partitioning cannot be changed for Queue. . 
TrackingId:8fbca9ae-e20f-40d7-af46-0ce061f1fd7f_M4CH3_M4CH3_G40, 
SystemTracker:servicebus01berkiot.servicebus.windows.net:berkiotqueue, 
Timestamp:5/16/2018 4:00:46 PM CorrelationId: a6dae9ed-c3c4-432a-b512- 
1ab02141f17b
```

What can be the cause of this issue?

Comment: What's your service bus resource location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was send this issue to the Azure Support, and they said there was an temporary issue on the system. After a short period of time the issue was resolved. Thank you for your interest.